# Show that $ax+ by+ cz\geq a^{x}.b^{y}.c^{z}$

Tags: inequality

Let $a, b, c, x, y, z> 0$ and $x+ y+ z= 1$. Show that
$$ax+ by+ cz\geq  a^{x}.b^{y}.c^{z}$$
I have found the generalization of this inequality:
For 2 sets of numbers $\left \{ a_{i} \right \}, \left \{ b_{i} \right \}> 0$ and $\sum_{1}^{n}b_{i}= 1$, we have:
$$\sum_{1}^{n}\left ( a_{i}b_{i} \right )\geq  \coprod_{1}^{n}\left ( a_{i}^{b_{i}} \right )$$
I try use Jensen inequality and Weight AM_ GM but I can' t because the LHS is a product with 
exponent numbers not integer. 
I hope to the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know Jensen's inequality?

Comment: This is weighted AM-GM.  See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Weighted_AM.E2.80.93GM_inequality

Comment: Some Vasc inequalities are on Discrete Inequalities Vol 5.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what Vasc inequalities are, but it results  from *Jensen's inequality*:

Simply compare the logs: as the natural logarithm is a concave function, one has
$$\ln\bigl(a^x b^y c^z)=x\ln a+y\ln b+z\ln c\le \ln(ax+by+cz) $$
for all non-negative $x,y,z$ such that $x+y+z=1$.

Comment: I don't think you wrote what you meant to write.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: You're right! Why do I so rarely rewrite my posts??? Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: I don' t accept because your solution be short. I want a more beautiful solution. However, thanks for your idea. That's good!

Comment: What do you mean by a  ‘more beautiful solution’? I don't say using *Jensen's inequality*  is exceptional, but I think it's illuminating and is readily generalised.